# Prevent mesh from going below the grid?

Tags: mesh

Hey all is there a way to prevent meshes from moving in the z axis below the grid?

I want to have a solid floor to work on Quickly without always needing to check the transform to 0 on Z

Comment: Hello :). You can simply lock the Z position in the transform panel (click the little lock icon)

Answer (score 4):

You could create a plane on Z = 0 (an empty will do, too, but you might want to hide what's below), then apply a **Mirror** modifier along Z around that plane, with **Clipping** enabled:

[image]

This will effectively clamp vertex positions:

[image]

If you leave a vertex at the plane, it will stick to it, and you will have to temporarily disable *Clipping* to be able to move it away:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a flat floor, you can simply lock the Z location in the Transform panel.
No matter how you'll move it, it'll stay at the same Z coordinates.

[image]